# find the value of current span value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list like below

```
<tr>
<td>val1</td>
<td>val2</td>
<td>val3</td>
<td><span class="span_view">1</span><a class="view_class">View</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>value1</td>
<td>value2</td>
<td>value3</td>
<td><span class="span_view">2</span><a class="view_class">View</a></td>
</tr>
```

If I click on view link then it should print the associated value of span e.g for the first view it will be 1 and for 2nd one it will be 2.
I have written the following code but it is not printing the value:

```
$('.view_class').live('click',function(){
   var parentDiv = $(this).closest('span');
   alert(parentDiv);
   var curprice=parentDiv.find('span[id=span_view]').val();
   alert(curprice);
 });
```

it is showing `[object Object]` and `undefined`.
Please guide me where is the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.view_class').on('click',function(){
   var parentDiv = $(this).parent();
   var curprice = parentDiv.find('.span_view').html();
   alert(curprice);
 });
```

Using the parent as the ***context*** to create more maintainable code. In case you need to re-order the spans, your code still works.

Or use delegated event to attach only 1 event handler and works also in case you load the list dynamically using ajax.

```
$(document).on('click','.view_class',function(){
       var parentDiv = $(this).parent();
       var curprice = parentDiv.find('.span_view').html();
       alert(curprice);
     });
```

Comment: @Mausumi: glad it helps. Your problem is `$(this).closest('span');` return a span up in the DOM (if there exists). And your selector `span[id=span_view]` looks for child span with `id=span_view` (should be with `class=span_view`)

Answer (score 2):

replace:

```
$('.view_class').live('click',function(){
   var parentDiv = $(this).closest('span');
   alert(parentDiv);
   var curprice=parentDiv.find('span[id=span_view]').val();
   alert(curprice);
 });
```

on:

```
$('.view_class').on('click',function(){
   var curprice=$(this).closest('span.span_view').html();
   alert(curprice);
 });
```

Comment: these don't work. The first looks for a span with `id=span_view` (span[id=span_view]), should be with class span_view. The second one does not work, too because `.closest` does not look for siblings.